# Cannot convert ‘boost::multiprecision::cpp_int

Tags: c++11, boost

**Giving this error on compilation:-
no matching function for call to ‘to_string(boost::multiprecision::cpp_int&)’ string s = to_string(i);**

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
using namespace std;

#define int long long int

int32_t main()
{
   mp::cpp_int l,i;
   for(i=l;i<r;i++)
    {
        string s = to_string(i); 
     }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I take int main() as int32_t main()

Answer (score 0):

You're including `boost::lexical_cast`'s header file and `boost::to_string`. Include the proper header file for `boost::to_string`, which is "`boost/exception/to_string.hpp`", or use `boost::lexical_cast`.